# error: C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

Tags: c++, qt

```
QList<DiagramzhiwuItem*> zhiwulist;

QList<Item*> zhiwus[zhiwuitemlist.count()];  // error here
```

Comment: The size of an array has to be compile-time computable. This is either a constant or might be a `constexpr`. `QList::count()` is not qualified `constexpr`.

Comment: Did you really intend to declare an array of `QList<Item*>`s? You may try a `QVector` instead of the array: `QVector<QList<Item*>> zhiwus(zhiwuitemlist.count());`.